# How to import a column of data with "%" with readxl?

Tags: r

I am importing data from Excel. I am using the package readxl to read the data. I have a column of data with both numbers as well as percentage values. Therefore, I want to import this column of data as text.

I used the [instructions on the package documentation page](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/cell-and-column-types.html#peek-at-column-names) how to define column types when importing data. However, even when the data is imported as text, it still converts the percentage to a number.

This is an example of what the data look like the field I am having trouble with:

```
data <- c(3200, 100%, 100, 100%)
```

The data frame after the import is showing that it is a character and not numeric. The results I expect would be the same as the vector above. However, what I am seeing is as follows:

```
output_after_import <- c(3200, 1, 100, 1)
```

When looking at the data in Excel, when I change the data type from "General" to "Text," the same problem occurs as shown in "output_after_import."

Comment: I think you can specify the `colClass`

Comment: can you open the excel file and save it as a text column

Comment: The problem is not in `readxl` as much as it is in Excel. In Excel (as much as in R), what you *see* (`100` and `100%`) is just a representation of the data. Internally, it is being *stored* numerically (`100` and `1.0`). So your issue isn't with R, it's with Excel. As Mike suggested, I believe your best step forward at this point is to tell Excel what format you want it *stored* as. (Using `openxlsx` produces the same results. Perhaps you can find a way to read what Excel thinks the formatting is for each cell, and adjust accordingly. Idk how yet.)

Comment: Probably easy way out is to use the Import Dataset option in RStudio., in the data preview window, choose character for the column containing the "100%" and import data. This will generate code in the preview window as appropriate that you can use for fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(readxl)
ExcelFile <- read_excel("ExcelFile.xlsx", col_types = c("numeric", "text"))
```